# how to use phpQuery with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, web, apache2, phpquery

I´m trying to use MarketBot with symfony but i`m getting the following error:

- I´ve phpQuery installed on my web server

This is my code:

```
$market = new \MarketBot\Android\GooglePlay;
$response = $market->get('PACKAGE_NAME', 'apps');
var_dump($response);
```

This is the error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'phpQuery' not found in /var/www/sf/src/MarketBot/MarketBot.php line 83
```

And this is the line which causes the error:

```
\phpQuery::newDocument($response);
```

If I change the previous line to:

```
phpQuery::newDocument($response);
```

The error is:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'MarketBot\phpQuery' not found in /var/www/sf/src/MarketBot/MarketBot.php line 83
```

I´ve already try many options but allways i´m getting different errors.

¿How can I say Symfony to execute phpQuery from the server and not from a local archive?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you include the phpQuery.php lib file in your MarketBot.php?
phpQuery doesn't use namespaces and doesn't have an autoloader, so you want to just require_once /path/to/phpQuery.php

Comment: @evgeny.chernyavskiy The library is already installed on webserver, i want to use it without include the php archive. (If i try to include phpQuery.php the way you say, the problems are others..., problems everywhere...) My web server has http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/downloads/detail?name=phpquery-0.9.5.386.deb installed

Comment: Hm, which PHP archive are you referring to? I suggest including phpQuery.php via require_once/include_once in your MarketBot.php. A quick look at the .deb file tells me phpQuery is installed in usr/lib/phpquery, so something like     require_once('/usr/lib/phpquery/phpQuery.php');should work perfectly. Alternatively add usr/lib/phpquery to the include_path and then just require_once('phpQuery.php');

Comment: @evgeny.chernyavskiy Finally I succeeded adding phpQuery.php next to MarketBot.php and modifying some parts of Market Bot to work properly, but now the problem is with the phpQuery when parsing the document, Now the error is: Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$tagName in /var/www/sf/src/MarketBot/phpQuery.php line 4186, and the line where it occurs: $xpath[] = $this->isXML()
                    ? "*[local-name()='{$node->tagName}'][{$i}]"
                    : "{$node->tagName}[{$i}]";  //HERE IS THE ERROR
                $node = $node->parentNode;

Comment: That's right, phpQuery abstracts [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) interactions via it's DOMDocumentWrapper class. It does not have a tagName property indeed.

Answer (score 2):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html
I praised the lord when found this component. PHPQuery is slow piece of … code